# Spring Boot STOMP lost connection after a few minutes

Tags: java, spring-websocket, activemq-artemis, sockjs

I am using ActiveMQ Artemis, SockJS, StompJS, Spring Boot STOMP.
When establishing the connection the client sends heart-beat info:

```
<<< CONNECTED
version:1.1
session:1913360c
server:ActiveMQ-Artemis/2.20.0 ActiveMQ Artemis Messaging Engine
heart-beat:10000,10000
user-name:qqq
```

The heartbeat is normal, but after several minutes the connection is closed by ActiveMQ. Here's the corresponding logs:

```
2022-03-03 09:30:09,718 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.stomp] AMQ332069: Sent ERROR frame to STOMP client /127.0.0.1:1432: AMQ229014: Did not receive data from /127.0.0.1:1432 within the 20,000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed.
2022-03-03 09:30:09,719 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222067: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ229014: Did not receive data from /127.0.0.1:1432 within the 20,000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed. [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT]
2022-03-03 09:30:09,719 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222061: Client connection failed, clearing up resources for session aa0cdab7-9a90-11ec-8b3d-6c02e05f997e
2022-03-03 09:30:09,725 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222107: Cleared up resources for session aa0cdab7-9a90-11ec-8b3d-6c02e05f997e
2022-03-03 09:58:45,120 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.stomp] AMQ332069: Sent ERROR frame to STOMP client /127.0.0.1:1922: AMQ229014: Did not receive data from /127.0.0.1:1922 within the 20,000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed.
2022-03-03 09:58:45,122 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222067: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ229014: Did not receive data from /127.0.0.1:1922 within the 20,000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed. [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT]
2022-03-03 09:58:45,122 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222061: Client connection failed, clearing up resources for session d2309f42-9a91-11ec-8b3d-6c02e05f997e
2022-03-03 09:58:45,125 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222107: Cleared up resources for session d2309f42-9a91-11ec-8b3d-6c02e05f997e
2022-03-03 10:14:16,758 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.stomp] AMQ332069: Sent ERROR frame to STOMP client /127.0.0.1:4003: AMQ229014: Did not receive data from /127.0.0.1:4003 within the 20,000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed.
2022-03-03 10:14:16,759 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222067: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ229014: Did not receive data from /127.0.0.1:4003 within the 20,000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed. [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT]
2022-03-03 10:14:16,759 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222061: Client connection failed, clearing up resources for session 939d58fd-9a95-11ec-8b3d-6c02e05f997e
2022-03-03 10:14:16,763 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222107: Cleared up resources for session 939d58fd-9a95-11ec-8b3d-6c02e05f997e
2022-03-03 10:14:53,112 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.stomp] AMQ332069: Sent ERROR frame to STOMP client null: null
2022-03-03 10:14:53,113 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222067: Connection failure has been detected: null [code=REMOTE_DISCONNECT]
2022-03-03 10:14:53,123 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.stomp] AMQ332069: Sent ERROR frame to STOMP client null: null
2022-03-03 10:14:53,123 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222067: Connection failure has been detected: null [code=REMOTE_DISCONNECT]
2022-03-03 10:21:34,506 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.stomp] AMQ332069: Sent ERROR frame to STOMP client /127.0.0.1:5140: AMQ229014: Did not receive data from /127.0.0.1:5140 within the 20,000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed.
2022-03-03 10:21:34,506 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222067: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ229014: Did not receive data from /127.0.0.1:5140 within the 20,000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed. [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT]
2022-03-03 10:21:34,507 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222061: Client connection failed, clearing up resources for session ce63aa1a-9a97-11ec-8b3d-6c02e05f997e
2022-03-03 10:21:34,510 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222107: Cleared up resources for session ce63aa1a-9a97-11ec-8b3d-6c02e05f997e
2022-03-03 11:21:29,133 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.stomp] AMQ332069: Sent ERROR frame to STOMP client /127.0.0.1:5582: AMQ229014: Did not receive data from /127.0.0.1:5582 within the 20,000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed.
2022-03-03 11:21:29,134 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222067: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ229014: Did not receive data from /127.0.0.1:5582 within the 20,000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed. [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT]
2022-03-03 11:21:29,134 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222061: Client connection failed, clearing up resources for session d1631205-9a98-11ec-8b3d-6c02e05f997e
2022-03-03 11:21:29,137 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222107: Cleared up resources for session d1631205-9a98-11ec-8b3d-6c02e05f997e
```

I tried several times, Refresh immediately when the last connection is lost. It's look stranger, sometimes the connection can hold half an hour, sometimes just a few minutes.

java code:

```java
    @Override
    protected void configureStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        //registry.enableSimpleBroker("/queue/", "/topic/", "/exchange/");
        registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/queue/", "/topic/", "/exchange/")
                .setSystemHeartbeatSendInterval(20000)
                .setSystemHeartbeatReceiveInterval(20000)
                .setTaskScheduler(heartBeatScheduler())
                
                .setRelayHost("127.0.0.1")
                .setRelayPort(61613)
                .setClientLogin("mirana")
                .setClientPasscode("mirana")
                .setSystemLogin("mirana")
                .setSystemPasscode("mirana");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }


  
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public UserDestinationResolver destinationResolver(SimpUserRegistry simpUserRegistry){
        return new DefaultUserDestinationResolver(simpUserRegistry){
            @Override
            public String getTargetDestination(String sourceDestination, String actualDestination,
                    String sessionId, @Nullable String user){
                return actualDestination + "-user-" + user;
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler heartBeatScheduler() {
        return new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    }
```

`server.js`:

```js
import Stomp from 'stompjs'
import Sockjs from 'sockjs-client'

var stompClient;

export function init(url){
    stompClient = Stomp.over(new Sockjs(url))
}


export function connect(successCallback, errorCallback){
    stompClient.connect({}, function(frame){
        successCallback(frame)
    }, function(frame){
        errorCallback(frame)
    })
}


export function subscribe(destination, callback){
    stompClient.subscribe(destination, message => callback(message))
}

export function send(destination, headers, object){
    stompClient.send(destination,headers,object)
}
```

`client.js`

```js
server.init('http://localhost:9999/ws?type=1&id=321feead21313fesa')
    server.connect(frame =>{
      console.log(frame)
      server.subscribe('/topic/chat.typing', message => {
        console.log("chat.type"+message)
      })
      server.subscribe('/topic/chat.message', message => {
        console.log("chat.message"+message)
      })
    }, frame =>{
      console.log(frame)
    })
}
```

Why are the lost connection intervals different? I am very confused.

I used localhost, not any WAN or LAN.

I set the log level to `TRACE` and the server doesn't receive the heart-beat from the client in 20s (the heartbeat is 10s at a time) then the broker closed the connection. So maybe it's the problem of the client. Maybe there's CPU spikes. This may need more tests to find the problem.

I try to inspect the client, and when the connection loses the status code is 1002, which means  `an endpoint is terminating the connection due to a protocol error`.
Does anybody know how to solve this problem.

Comment: I didn't inspect my network, I used localhost, not any WAN or LAN. did localhost also have this problem?

Comment: I set the log level to trace and the server exactly don't receive the heartbeat from the client in 20s (the heartbeat is 10s at a time) then the MQ broke the connection. So, maybe it's the problem of the client, maybe the CPU spikes, this may need more tests to find the problem

Comment: In my opinion, since the client cannot guarantee a continuous and stable heartbeat, the server is responsible for sending the heartbeat to MQ. The client only needs to keep the connection but does not need to send a heartbeat to ensure whether it is online. After a certain period, the server initiates an initiative to ask whether the client is available  If the client disconnects, the server stops sending heartbeat messages using the connection information.

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help other folks who have this same question in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your opinion does not conform to the STOMP specification. If the client cannot guarantee a heart-beat according to the value it sends in the `heart-beat` header of the `CONNECT` frame then it should send a **different value**. In your case you're sending `10000` for the client heart-beat. Therefore, the broker will expect heart-beats from the client based on this value, and if it doesn't receive those heart-beats then it will disconnect that client. If you don't want the client to send heart-beats then you should send `0`, e.g. `heart-beat:0,10000`.

Also, the broker reports that it closed the client's connection after "20,000ms" because by default it will multiple the client heart-beat value by `2` (e.g. `10000 * 2 = 20000`). It does this because the [STOMP specification](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#Heart-beating) recommends incorporating a margin for timing errors:

> because of timing inaccuracies, the receiver SHOULD be tolerant and take into account an error margin

Comment: Thanks, my opinion is bad, I will try to solve the problem of the client